Unable to compile class for JSP: The method prs(java.lang.String, java.lang.String, javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest) in the type Htmlforms
I upgraded from Apache Tomcat 9 to 10, but when I uploaded my project (developed a few years ago) I got the following error
An error occurred at line: [9] in the jsp file: [/index.jsp]
The method prs(java.lang.String, java.lang.String, javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest) in the type Htmlforms is not applicable for the arguments (java.lang.String, java.lang.String, jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest)
7: String path = request.getContextPath();
8: String basePath = request.getScheme()+"://"+request.getServerName()+":"+request.getServerPort()+path+"/";
9: String sClose=hf.prs("Close","",request);
    
11: voUser vo=(voUser)  session.getAttribute("usuario");

I tried to compile locally, but it still gives me the same error. Update to java version 11
Should I make any changes to the code or any component?
